# Too many methods in a project

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, compilation, javac

I understand that this question was asked a lot, but hear me out.

Compilation of Android (debug) project through Eclipse (ecj) succeeds (apk is generated), but when the same code with the same libraries is compiled through ant (javac) I'm getting compilation error (dx stage).

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

The problem isn't the message itself but the lack of it while compiling the project through Eclipse.

Can someone explain why Eclipse succeeds and Ant fails?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse succeeds in building the project but the error is actually generated later - when you run the project. I think it's because this is when all the libraries and (related) projects are linked in one apk.

Comment: I just checked, and the Eclipse (debug) apk runs just fine.

Comment: Do you use proguard with the eclipse build to remove unused methods?

Comment: Proguard is only enabled when publishing apk, not while creating debug apks.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [this](http://www.betaful.com/2013/10/android-too-many-methods-dex-fails/) great post

Comment: Please do not "litter" in this question with irrelevant answers.